# Hi I'm Japanese, I'd like know the difference between "evidence" and "proof"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, expressions, differences, british-english

Which one is more common in daily conversation, like when you are talking to a friend?

I understand **"evidence"** as having a more specific meaning, such as a particular experiment in physics, and used for important issues. On the other hand, I understand **"proof"** is more likely to be used between friends. For example,

- "Did you go out with anyone last night?" "No, I didn't. this picture proves it."
- "We have finally found some evidence four our diagnostic hypothesis."

Do I understand both words correctly?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to English Language & Usage. Could you edit this post with your research, please, concerning *evidence* versus *proof*, say with dictionary definitions?

Comment: The fact that you can walk 100 miles and not end up leaning to one side is evidence that the earth is flat.

Comment: *Evidence* is a suggestion. It makes you wonder. *Proof* is a fact. It makes you know.

Answer (score 3):

Cambridge Dictionary defines **[evidence](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/evidence)** as "*one or more reasons for believing something is or is not true*." On the other hand, it defines **[proof](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proof)** as "*a fact or piece of information that shows that something exists or is true*."

The word **proof** is, therefore, **more definite and sufficient than evidence** when it comes to uncovering the truth. However, people might use it in casual communication more often purely out of practicality. It's fairly easy to pronounce "proof."